# Создание Tab в главном окне на WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi, tab

Достаточно долго искал информацию в интернете по поводу создания закладок tab в окне на WinApi. Пробовал многие способы и отрывки кода, не добился успеха и результата. Мой код должен создавать закладки, но высвечиваются ошибки:

> Ошибка (активно)   E0513   значение типа "const char *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "LPWSTR".

> Ошибка C2440   =: невозможно преобразовать "const char [6]" в "LPWSTR".

Upd. Прикрепляю скриншоты ошибок.
[image: Ошибки.]
[image: Ошибки]

Как можно было бы решить эту проблему, чтобы код работал корректно и успешно создались закладки?
Мой код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // Инициализация библиотеки коммон-контролов
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icc;
    icc.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icc.dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icc);

    // Регистрация класса окна
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MainWindowClass";
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Создание главного окна
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        L"MainWindowClass", L"Tab Control Example",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 800, 600,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hWnd) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window creation failed!", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        return -1;
    }

    // Отображение главного окна
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Основной цикл сообщений
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    static HWND hTab;

    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CREATE: {

        // Создание и добавление элемента управления вкладками
        hTab = CreateWindow(
            WC_TABCONTROL, L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            10, 10, 760, 500,
            hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        // Добавление вкладок 

        TCITEM tie;
        tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
        tie.pszText = L"Tab 1"; // Здесь ошибки.
        TabCtrl_InsertItem(hTab, 0, &tie);

        tie.pszText = L"Tab 2"; // Здесь ошибки.
        TabCtrl_InsertItem(hTab, 1, &tie);

        tie.pszText = L"Tab 3"; // Здесь ошибки.
        TabCtrl_InsertItem(hTab, 2, &tie);

        break;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

В целом хорошо было бы показать простой пример добавления tab закладок в главное окно в WinApi, который работает без ошибок.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Upd#2. [image: Новые ошибки.]

Comment: `tie.pszText = L"Tab 1"; // Здесь ошибки.` - приведенный текст ошибок не соответствует этому коду.

Comment: @user7860670 обновил вопрос, добавил скриншоты ошибок для понятия.

Comment: Текст в вопросе не соответствует тексту на скриншотах... Но вообще сделайте просто `tie.pszText = const_cast<LPWSTR>(L"Tab 1");`. Редкий случай, когда такой каст оправдан.

Comment: @user7860670 изменил по вашему совету код, новые ошибки... уже системные... (прикрепил фотографию в конец вопроса.) Что делать?

Comment: *"Прикрепляю скриншоты ошибок."* - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119 А если ошибка исправлена и появились какие-то другие, то следует задать новый вопрос, предварительно убедившись, что он не был задан ранее.

Comment: За оформление и вид публикации ошибок в виде скриншотов извиняюсь. Делал так, ибо так ошибки визуально понятнее, нежели копировать каждую и вставлять, это лично моё мнение, но правила есть правила, я понимаю.
Насчёт темы, если опустить момент с новыми ошибками, есть ли у вас возможность показать простой и базовый шаблон создания tab закладок для окна, которые будут работать без ошибок? Ибо я достаточно долго бродил по интернету, но либо темы очень старые, либо код смешанный. Спасибо.